# Remote wsus querying with ansible : 401 unauthorized with valid accounts

Tags: windows, powershell, ansible, winrm, windows-update

I was writting my first powershell script to get statistics about around 300 servers dispatched on 3 WSUS servers. There's an upstream and two downstream servers (one autonomous and one replica).

The powershell script is sent to the upstream server before execution with the help of an ansible playbook (using winrm connection).

The script simply parses two configured hosts (the upstream and the autonomous downstream) then calls the Get-WsusServer and subsequent routines to get the data i need.

When the powershell script is ran directly on the upstream host, all is fine, and the Get-WsusServer with the autonomous server works.

When the powershell script is ran by the ansible playbook, it fails with the following error when the Get-WsusServer routine calls the autnonomous downstream server :

```
    "stderr_lines": [
    "Get-WsusServer : The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.",
    "At D:\\Reports\\wsusreport.ps1:74 char:11",
    "+   $wsus = Get-WsusServer -Name $wsusserver -PortNumber 8530",
    "+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~",
    "    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Updat...usServerCommand:GetWsusServerCommand) [Get-WsusServer],  ",
    "   WebException",
    "    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ServerIsInvalid,Microsoft.UpdateServices.Commands.GetWsusServerCommand",
    " ",
    "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.",
    "At D:\\Reports\\wsusreport.ps1:80 char:3",
    "+   $classifications=$wsus.GetUpdateClassifications() |",
    "+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~",
    "    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException",
    "    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull",
    " ",
    "Exception calling \"AddRange\" with \"1\" argument(s): \"Value cannot be null.",
    "Parameter name: value\"",
```

I tried using a domain account, with local admin privileges, and also with local admin accounts. But i cant put the finger on what the problem really is.

And i cant manage to explain the behavior difference between the local execution which is successful, and the execution with the playbook which fails when calling Get-WsusServer against the autonomous downstream server.

Additional information :
The powershell script loop looks like :

```
  $Target_WSUS_Server_host = "upstream", "downstream"

  foreach ($domain in $Target_WSUS_Server_Host) {

  Write-Host "Working on : $domain"

  [void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration')
  $wsus = Get-WsusServer -Name $domain -PortNumber 8530 

  # Scope initialization
  $computerscope = New-Object Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.ComputerTargetScope 
  $computerscope.IncludeDownstreamComputerTargets = 'true'

  etc....
```

The ansible piece of playbook is quite basic and just plays the win_shell module after the script is copied. If i only query the upstream, the ansible play is 100% OK.

```
---
- name: wsus report generation
  hosts: upstream
  vars:
    local_dir: "./data/"
    local_script: "wsusreport.ps1"
    remote_script_log: "wsusreport.log"
    remote_dir: 'D:\Reports\'
    script_log: "wsusreport.log"
    yearmonth: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y-%m') }}"
  tasks:
  - name: copy ps1 script to wsus server
    tags:
      - sendscript
    win_copy:
      src: "{{ local_dir }}/{{ local_script }}"
      dest: "{{ remote_dir }}"

  - name: execute script
    tags:
      - exescript
    win_shell: "{{ remote_dir }}\\{{ local_script }} downstream {{ yearmonth }} > {{ remote_dir }}\\{{ remote_script_log }}"
```

The powershell script takes two parameters,
 first one is a switch to determine if i want just the upstream data, the downstream data or both.
 the second one is the time range i wanna retrieve, which defaults to current patch tuesday campaign.

**Additionnal information**

On the security event log, what happens when the script is dropped and called by ansible :
 - There's a logon/logout events with those details :

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" Guid="{54849625-5478-4994-A5BA-3E3B0328C30D}" /> 
  <EventID>4624</EventID> 
  <Version>2</Version> 
  <Level>0</Level> 
  <Task>12544</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8020000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-01-03T15:44:11.016233500Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>3662170</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation ActivityID="{1715CB99-B4FA-0001-A1CB-1517FAB4D501}" /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="792" ThreadID="4316" /> 
  <Channel>Security</Channel> 
  <Computer>*FQDN of the downstream server*</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="SubjectUserSid">S-1-0-0</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectUserName">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectDomainName">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectLogonId">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="TargetUserSid">S-1-5-7</Data> 
  <Data Name="TargetUserName">ANONYMOUS LOGON</Data>  <===== /!\
  <Data Name="TargetDomainName">NT AUTHORITY</Data>
  <Data Name="TargetLogonId">0x13316e110</Data> 
  <Data Name="LogonType">3</Data> 
  <Data Name="LogonProcessName">NtLmSsp</Data> 
  <Data Name="AuthenticationPackageName">NTLM</Data> 
  <Data Name="WorkstationName">*Hostname of the upstream server*</Data> 
  <Data Name="LogonGuid">{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</Data> 
  <Data Name="TransmittedServices">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="LmPackageName">NTLM V1</Data> 
  <Data Name="KeyLength">128</Data> 
  <Data Name="ProcessId">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="ProcessName">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="IpAddress">*IP Adress of the upstream server*</Data> 
  <Data Name="IpPort">55186</Data> 
  <Data Name="ImpersonationLevel">%%1833</Data> 
  <Data Name="RestrictedAdminMode">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="TargetOutboundUserName">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="TargetOutboundDomainName">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="VirtualAccount">%%1843</Data> 
  <Data Name="TargetLinkedLogonId">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="ElevatedToken">%%1843</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

When the script is called directly on the upstream server, the logon process is far more verbose, and uses the local account which is the same between the two servers.

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" Guid="{54849625-5478-4994-A5BA-3E3B0328C30D}" /> 
  <EventID>4624</EventID> 
  <Version>2</Version> 
  <Level>0</Level> 
  <Task>12544</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8020000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-01-03T15:44:46.197671000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>3662174</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation ActivityID="{1715CB99-B4FA-0001-A1CB-1517FAB4D501}" /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="792" ThreadID="5672" /> 
  <Channel>Security</Channel> 
  <Computer>DOWNSTREAM_SERVER_FQDN</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="SubjectUserSid">S-1-0-0</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectUserName">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectDomainName">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="SubjectLogonId">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="TargetUserSid">S-1-5-21-910770422-2570656215-934337312-1006</Data> 
  <Data Name="TargetUserName">ACCOUNT_USED_ON_BOTH_SERVERS</Data> <====== OK !
  <Data Name="TargetDomainName">DOWNSTREAM_SERVER_HOSTNAME</Data> 
  <Data Name="TargetLogonId">0x13319dcbb</Data> 
  <Data Name="LogonType">3</Data> 
  <Data Name="LogonProcessName">NtLmSsp</Data> 
  <Data Name="AuthenticationPackageName">NTLM</Data> 
  <Data Name="WorkstationName">UPSTREAM_SERVER_HOSTNAME</Data> 
  <Data Name="LogonGuid">{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</Data> 
  <Data Name="TransmittedServices">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="LmPackageName">NTLM V2</Data> 
  <Data Name="KeyLength">128</Data> 
  <Data Name="ProcessId">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="ProcessName">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="IpAddress">UPSTREAM_SERVER_IP_ADDRESS</Data> 
  <Data Name="IpPort">55198</Data> 
  <Data Name="ImpersonationLevel">%%1833</Data> 
  <Data Name="RestrictedAdminMode">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="TargetOutboundUserName">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="TargetOutboundDomainName">-</Data> 
  <Data Name="VirtualAccount">%%1843</Data> 
  <Data Name="TargetLinkedLogonId">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="ElevatedToken">%%1842</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Comment: You didn't show the ansible tasks copying and running the script. The problem seems to be somewhere there... Are you passing any parameters ? Please update you question with the playbook you are using (or at least the relevant parts).

Comment: added a few lines, the playbook runs fine when i'm pulling only upstream data, but when i ask the powershell script to pull downstream data, it fails with mentionned error.
The exact same script is ok, when executed from an opened session on the upstream server.

Comment: Did you try to quote the date inside your command ? `win_shell: "{{ remote_dir }}\\{{ local_script }} downstream \"{{ yearmonth }}\" > {{ remote_dir }}\\{{ remote_script_log }}"... just a thought, else I'll let someone else look into it as I have no other idea.

Comment: Thanks, but the script fails during the execution, and it doesnt looks like it is related to the parameters, actually, i just ran without the yearmonth parameter, the script knows how to handle it. 
The error really pops up, when the script it self tries to Get-WsusServer with the remote downstream server. Though it is ok when the same script and same parameters are used locally, when logged in the upstream server.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_winrm.html#authentication-options
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/become.html#become-and-windows

The ntlm method doesnt let you assume the correct grants of the account you are using to run a win_shell command or instruction.

I had to swap ntlm for kerberos and use become feature with runas method, and specify the exact same account i'm using for the winrm connection.

It is working.